# Pandas - Groupby object behavior

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am struggeling currently with the behavior of of the pandas groupby object. I have just switched from version 0.2.5 to 1.2.3 and my code does not behave the same anymore.

In version 0.2.5 when I did a groupby by multiple columns all lines where the result was 0 were basically dropped. But in the recent version I am using I get that all unique values from each columns are grouped leading to many lines showing 0 as a result thereof.

Code example:

```
df.groupby(['ColumnA', 'ColumnB'])['ColumnC'].count()
```

Result in 0.2.5:

ColumnA | ColumnB | Result of Count

Result in 1.2.3:
Column A - Value 1 | Column B - Value 1 | 2
Column A - Value 1 | Column B - Value 2 | 0
Column A - Value 2 | Column B - Value 1 | 0
Column A - Value 2 | Column B - Value 2 | 0

This creates a lot of unnecessary lines which are bascially useless. This becomes especially annoying when you work with large dataset of millions of lines and thousands of unique values per column. How can I force the behaviour from my previous version because this would mean that I would have to redo a lot of function which I have created. What did I missed in the transition from the different versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems working with Categoricals, need parameter `observed=True` for avoid add missing categories to [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

> **observed**, default False

> This only applies if any of the groupers are Categoricals. If True: only show observed values for categorical groupers. If False: show all values for categorical groupers.

```
df.groupby(['ColumnA', 'ColumnB'], observed=True)['ColumnC'].count()
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the data from a pickle file and it seems that the data was indeed saved as a categorical data even though I did not specially changed that data format. I have misread the pandas helpfil as I thought that everything below the "Deprecated since version 1.1.0." applies to all below. But that was the solution. Thanks!